# aggregate/sum with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to sum data with `ggplot2` ?

I want to do a bubble map with the size depending of the sum of z.

Currently I'm doing something like

```
dd <- ddply(d, .(x,y), transform, z=sum(z))
qplot(x,y, data=dd, size=z)
```

But I feel I'm writing the same thing twice, I would like to be able to write something

```
qplot(x,y, data=dd, size=sum(z))
```

I had a look at `stat_sum` and `stat_summmary` but I'm not sure they are appropriate either.

Is it possible to it with `ggplot2` ? If not, what would be best way to write those 2 lines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can be done using `stat_sum` within ggplot2. By default, the dot size represents proportions. To get dot size to represent counts, use `size = ..n..` as an aesthetic. Counts (and proportions) by a third variable can be obtained by weighting by the third variable (`weight = cost`) as an aesthetic.  Some examples, but first, some data.

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed = 321
# Generate somme data
df <- expand.grid(x = seq(1:5), y = seq(1:5), KEEP.OUT.ATTRS = FALSE)
df$Count = sample(1:25, 25, replace = F)
library(plyr)
new <- dlply(df, .(Count), function(data) matrix(rep(matrix(c(data$x, data$y), ncol = 2), data$Count), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 2))
df2 <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, new))
df2$cost <- 1:325
```

The data contains units categorised according to two factors: X1 and X2; and a third variable which is the cost of each unit.

Plot 1: Plots the **proportion** of elements at each X1 - X2 combination. `group=1` tells ggplot to calculate proportions out of the total number of units in the data frame.

```
ggplot(df2, aes(factor(X1), factor(X2))) + 
  stat_sum(aes(group = 1))
```

[image]

Plot 2: Plots the **number** of elements at each X1 - X2 combination.

```
ggplot(df2, aes(factor(X1), factor(X2))) + 
  stat_sum(aes(size = ..n..))
```

[image]

Plot 3: Plots the cost of the elements at each X1 - X2 combination, that is `weight` by the third variable.

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x=factor(X1), y=factor(X2))) + 
     stat_sum(aes(group = 1, weight = cost, size = ..n..))
```

[image]

Plot 4: Plots the proportion of the total cost of all elements in the data frame at each X1 - X2 combination

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x=factor(X1), y=factor(X2))) + 
     stat_sum(aes(group = 1, weight = cost))
```

[image]

Plot 5: Plots proportions, but instead of the proportion being out of the total cost across all elements in the data frame, the proportion is out of the cost for elements within each category of X1. That is, within each X1 category, where does the major cost for X2 units occur?

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x=factor(X1), y=factor(X2))) + 
     stat_sum(aes(group = X1, weight = cost))
```

[image]

Comment: Is the answer to my question plot #3 then ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said so. Yes.

Comment: @SandyMuspratt For all plots with proportions (e.g., Plot 1), I had to explicitly ask ggplot for the proportion to be plotted using: `aes(group = 1, size=..prop.. )`.  
As this is an old post, the standard could depend on the ggplot version but it could still help someone!

Answer (score 2):

You could put the `ddply` call into the `qplot`:

```
d <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10, z= runif(100))
qplot(x, y, data=ddply(d, .(x,y), transform, z=sum(z)), size=z)
```

Or use the `data.table` package.

```
DT <- data.table(d, key='x,y')
qplot(x, y, data=DT[, sum(z), by='x,y'], size=V1)
```

Comment: I know I can do that, Your solutions are equivalent to my first attempt. I want to avoid having to specify 'x,y' twice (in the same lines or in 2 different lines)